# How to show Sign Out when the user signs in

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to set the sign out function on my app. Most of my HTML pages I have a sign in button and a sign out button.

```
<button class="SignInBtn" id="SignInBtn">Sign In</button>
<button class="SignOutBtn" id="SignOutBtn">Sign Out</button>

firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
    if (user) {
      document.getElementById("SignInBtn").style.visibility = "hidden";              
      document.getElementById("SignOutBtn").style.visibility = "visible";
    } else {
      document.getElementById("SignOutBtn").style.visibility = "hidden";                 
      document.getElementById("SignInBtn").style.visibility = "visible";
    }  
});
```

Basically, I want the buttons to display as "Sign Out" when the user has signed in. My buttons seem to all say Sign In whenever my user has signed in?

Comment: I'm not familiar with firebase, but you noted JS in the question tag... What is wrong with setting a JS cookie to indicate a user has signed in? You do this via `document.cookie='logged in'` and then you can easily alter your button based on the fact that this cookie is set or not...FYI pretty much every login system (I have ever developed) uses cookies to store data similar to this. Here is the W3 link for complete JS cookie info... I'd suggest server sided cookies though: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

Comment: The HTML and code look good at first sight. If you replace the whole `if` block with a simple `console.log(user)` and run again, what does it print?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you opposed to using jQuery? It's as easy as:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  $('#SignInButton, #SignOutButton').toggle();
}
```

direct updates to document are sometimes funky so I recommend giving jquery a swing.